# Access array holding database query results from within function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm doing three almost identical MySQL-queries and I'm looking to create a function to handle the three variants, instead of repeating the whole block of code three times. The variable I'm trying to pass to the function is the array holding the query results.

My PHP-code, super-simplified:

```
function list_comments( $query ) {
     echo '<p>' . $query->Comment . '</p>';
}

$theQuery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Ny = 1 ORDER BY UserID, Date DESC");

list_comments( $theQuery );
```

I've tried using variables variable to re-create the variable name inside the function, I've tried returning the result instead of echoing it out, and I've tried using the dynamic way of creating variable names inside the function; `${$query}`. But everything gives me the same result:

> Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or
>   Object. Incorrect value given in
>   C:***\www\wp_***\wp-content\themes***\includes\admin_***.php
>   on line 41

The line being referenced to as line 41 would be the line `function list_comments( $query ) {` above.

Is there a way to either access the `$theQuery`-array from within the function, or to return the value to where the function is being called before it's being evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

the parameter in method http_build_query you defined is expected to be an type of array or object, obviously it is receiving something other than that. In order to fix the error you should post the the piece of code where you are calling the method from (C:***\www\wp_*\wp-content\themes*\includes\admin_***.php on line 41) so we can take a look at that.

Also note that you got a typo on your method `list_comments()` param where `theQuery` should be `$theQuery`